# Converting SyndFeed to SyndEntry with Rome

Tags: java, feed, atom-feed, rome

I'm currently working on a project which implies XML feed parsing (Atom 2005) and I'm using Rome to do this.

I have currently two kind of XML structure to parse.

The first type :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xml:base="..." >

    <id>...</id>

    <title type="text" >...</title>

    <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" >
    <id>...</id>
    </entry>

    <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" >
    <id>...</id>
    </entry>

    ...
</feed>
```

(One feed, containing several entries)

The second type :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" >
    <id>...</id>
</entry>
```

(One entry, but it is not contained in a "feed")

My objective is to make a bean "MyEntry" which parse input XML and get information. My ideal would be to have ONE constructor (which takes an SyndEntry as argument for example).

I did that :

```
public MyEntry( SyndEntry e ) {
    _entry = e;
}
```

I can get "SyndEntry" objects when I get *first* type of XML feed :

```
SyndFeedInput feed_input = new SyndFeedInput();
...
SyndFeed feed = feed_input.build(xml_file);

for ( SyndEntry e : feed.getEntries() ) {
    // I can get SyndEntries from here
}
```

--> But with the second type of XML, there is not "feed" container and I can't find any method to build SyndEntry from XML directly (like a "SyndEntryInput" ?). I get a "SyndFeed" instead of a "SyndEntry", even if all information remains accessible.

Thus, I'm looking for a way to convert SyndFeed to SyndEntry (or reverse), using a superclass (I can't find any superclass common to SyndEntry and SyndFeed) or a dedicated converter.

My current solution is to make two constructors (one taking "SyndFeed", and other one taking "SyndEntry"), but it's quite ugly because I've a method "getSyndData()" which ideally returns object used for construction, usefull for retrieving generic info (ie: getSyndData().getTitle())

Any help or idea would be appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting XML String value of SyndEntry with ROME](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187928/getting-xml-string-value-of-syndentry-with-rome)

Answer (score 0):

Answered myself here : [Getting XML String value of SyndEntry with ROME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187928/getting-xml-string-value-of-syndentry-with-rome/16238401#16238401)

Maybe I didn't asked the right question