# Getting XML String value of SyndEntry with ROME

Tags: java, xml, atom-feed, rome

I'm currently working on a project which implies XML feed parsing (Atom 2005) and I'm using Rome to do this.

I have some SyndEntry objects, and I need to convert them to XML as standalone Entries (not in *Feeds*, Entry as root element).

I looking for a way to get something like that from a **SyndEntry** object :

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
   <title type="text">My Title</title>
   <updated>1988-01-01T00:00:00Z</updated>
   <content type="application/xml">
      ... (my content) ...
   </content>
</entry>
```

--> Without *Feed* objects.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got it !

```
Entry entry = Atom10Parser.parseEntry(reader, "");
```

Then you have an Entry object. If ou want a SyndEntry object, you can do :

```
public class MyConverterForAtom10 extends ConverterForAtom10 {

public SyndEntry syndEntryFromEntry( Entry entry ) {
    return this.createSyndEntry(null,entry,false);
}

public Entry entryFromSyndEntry( SyndEntry syndentry ) {
    return this.createAtomEntry(syndentry);
}

}
```